# PHP: how can I access JSON object

Tags: php, json, post

I'm sending this JSON:

```
[{"tipo":""},{"activo":""},{"titulo":"Servicoasd B"},{"texto":"asdasdasd"}]
```

to a php file via post method.

There, i do

```
$obj = json_decode($_POST['sentJson']);
```

However, I seem to be unable to access the elements of the JSON.

```
var_dump(($obj));
```

Shows the object:

```
array(4) {
  [0]=>
  object(stdClass)#2 (1) {
    ["tipo"]=>
    string(0) ""
  }
  [1]=>
  object(stdClass)#3 (1) {
    ["activo"]=>
    string(0) ""
  }
  [2]=>
  object(stdClass)#4 (1) {
    ["titulo"]=>
    string(9) "Servico B"
  }
  [3]=>
  object(stdClass)#5 (1) {
    ["texto"]=>
    string(6) "asdasd"
  }
}
```

But if I try

```
$obj['texto'];
$obj->{'texto'};
$obj[0]['texto'];
$obj[0];
```

It shows "undefined index texto" or "trying to get property of non object in" and the last one "Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string in". I'm very new to PHP, but still I can't seem to notice what I'm doing wrong. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: technical note: there is no such thing as a "JSON object". There's JSON, which is a string, and there is "the object that you get by parsing that JSON". And yes, when asking programming questions, that technical difference matters. As for your question: sure, your JSON is for an _array_ of objects (look at the JSON itself, which is pretty clear about that fact), so `$obj` is an array and you access its elements using `$obj[0]` etc.

Comment: `$obj` appears to be an array...

Comment: `$obj[3]->texto`

Answer (score 0):

Your JSON is a serialized array of four completely different objects, so when you run `json_decode`, that's what you get: an array.

If you want to access your objects inside that array, access them like you would any other indexed array:

```php
$list = json_decode(...);
foreach($list as $obj) {
  var_dump($obj)
}
```

Or target them explicitly using plain old numerical access.

```php
$list = json_decode(...);
$last = $list[3];
$text = $last->texto;
```

But really the question you should be asking is why this is the JSON you get. An array with completely different objects at each position is terrible data, and should be fixed.